# How should new line and bold/italic characters be stored?

Tags: mysql, html

I want to store paragraphs in my database. This includes some bold and italic characters. Is there any datatype in MySQL for this; or, should I store the data in a varchar column?

How should new line and bold/italic characters by stored in MySQL?

Comment: Why do you believe that bold and italic are CHARACTERS? They're TAGS! Plain text. Any text-type field will do.

Comment: Unless you're dealing with raw printer output or something, I'm guessing you mean `<b>` and `<i>` html tags? Those are just text...

Comment: I am assuming this because the poster has an HTML tag on this question.

Comment: @Diodeus: Good point.  I didn't see that!  :)

Answer (score 2):

you can't you have to store html code in varchar/text datatype field in mysql and then just echo it without using htmlspecialchars()

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of below data type depending on your requirement. Don't worry about bold or italic. since all those are in character format inside html.

```
TEXT        A string with a maximum length of 65535 characters.
BLOB        A string with a maximum length of 65535 characters.
MEDIUMTEXT  A string with a maximum length of 16777215 characters.
MEDIUMBLOB  A string with a maximum length of 16777215 characters.
LONGTEXT    A string with a maximum length of 4294967295 characters.
LONGBLOB    A string with a maximum length of 4294967295 characters.
```